# Wordpress - MySQL query to show posts only from a specific category

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the following query that bring the posts that contain a specific word in the title

```
SELECT posts_post.ID AS post_ID,
       posts_post.post_date AS post_post_date,
       CONCAT('<a href="',posts_post.guid,'">',posts_post.post_title,'</a>') AS post_title_with_link_to_post
FROM wp_posts AS posts_post
WHERE 1=1 
  AND posts_post.post_title LIKE '%HOTARAR%'
  AND posts_post.post_type = 'post'
GROUP BY post_post_date
```

The problem now is that I need to bring the posts only from a specific category (tag slug for the category is hotarari-consiliu-local and has the ID 160), how could I modify the above query to bring posts only from a single blog posts category? Thanks!

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: @Strawberry - could you help me modify the query from first post to extract from only a single category? I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Bhautik is on the right path, then something like this should work (I don't know where 'hotarari-consiliu-local' belongs in this).

```
   SELECT p.ID post_ID
        , p.post_date post_post_date
        , CONCAT('<a href="',p.guid,'">',p.post_title,'</a>') post_title_with_link_to_post
     FROM wp_posts p
     JOIN wp_term_relationships pt
       ON pt.object_id = p.ID 
     JOIN wp_term_taxonomy t
       ON t.term_taxonomy_id = pt.term_taxonomy_id 
    WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
      AND p.post_title LIKE '%HOTARAR%'
      AND t.taxonomy = 'category'
      AND t.term_id = 160
    ORDER 
       BY  post_date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, did the necessary changes to match the database prefix but i get this `Rendered query: SELECT p.ID post_ID, p.post_date post_post_date, CONCAT('',p.post_title,'') post_title_with_link_to_post FROM wpo8_posts p INNER JOIN wpo8_term_relationships pt ON pt.object_id = p.ID INNER JOIN wpo8_term_taxonomy t ON t.term_taxonomy_id = pt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND t.taxonomy = 'category' AND t.term_taxonomy.term_id = 160 ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 10
MySQL said: Unknown column 't.term_taxonomy.term_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: OK. Edited accordingly

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the help @Strawberry and Bhautik

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query.

```
global $wpdb;
$make = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM 
        $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN 
        $wpdb->term_relationships 
    ON
        ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN 
        $wpdb->term_taxonomy 
    ON
        ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE 
        $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND 
        $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%HOTARAR%'
    AND 
        $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND 
        $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 160
    ORDER BY 
        post_date DESC
");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Bhautik. The thing is I am using wpdatatables plugin, and I need to have the query formatted like this [https://i.ibb.co/KzxvCDw/wpdatatables.png]

Comment: Will try again, should be ok now - https://i.ibb.co/KzxvCDw/wpdatatables.png . It will only work if I modify the query from initial post above.

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN